# How can I map the "Print Screen" button to start a "crosshair" screenshot via Skitch app on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, screenshot

<kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> is supposedly the shortcut / hotkey to start a crosshair screenshot, but:

A) That hotkey doesn't work very well.

(What I want to replicate is the type of crosshair screenshot I can take by clicking the Skitch icon in the top of my screen and then clicking Crosshair Screenshot.)

B) I much prefer <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>

P.S. I'm using a Logitech USB wireless Windows-style keyboard, so I do have a <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key (among many others).

Comment: Can you elaborate on does not work very well ?   It works for me every time.

Comment: Macs don't have a PrintScreen key. You can take the crosshair screenshot using Cmd/Shift/4 as well as the more complex Cmd/Shift/5 implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm do not think MacOS provides a way to remap <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> natively.

That said, you can turn off the shortcut for <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> which might be causing your sporadic behaviour and let Skitch's shortcut through.

Select System Preferences and the Keyboard option.  Then deselect the shortcut sequence like this:

[image]

Hopefully that will at least improve the stability of the shortcut.

Comment: I've posted a new version on the Apple StackExchange. I'm really hoping it's possible to make use of my <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461781/using-a-windows-keyboard-how-can-i-map-the-print-screen-button-to-open-flames